# Macro to input a '1' in new column if row matches unique ID and contains text of column header

Tags: vba, excel

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me formulate a spreadsheet.  I have a simple spreadsheet with multiple repeated IDs per row in column 1, all containing a type of diagnosis in column 2 - each patient could have between 1 and 20 different variations.

(Sorry I'm not allowed to post an image)

Sheet 1

```
c_ID | Diagnosis
-----| ---------
1    | a
1    | c
2    | a
3    | a
3    | s
4    | h
4    | g
4    | f
```

I would like to make it so that each patient is only on one row, so I have created a new Table with each patient ID only once, and then a column header for each diagnosis.

Sheet 2

```
c_ID | a | b | c | d | e ... | s
```

In each row, I would like to return a '1' where the patient ID matches and one of the specified diagnoses for that patient ID matches the column header, and a '0' where it does not.

i.e. I want to write something in Sheet 2 like: If the c_ID in column 1 in Sheet 2 matches the c_ID in column 1 in Sheet 1, then for that c_ID search sheet 1 column 2 to see if any of the data for that c_ID matches any of the column headers columns 2-21 in sheet 2, and if yes return a 1 and if no return a 0.

I have no experience in writing macros, or VBA, but I wondered if it is possible to do so?  I would be very grateful for any help, or advice as to a better way to go about this.

Comment: Excel has built in functionality - have a look at using a pivot table before you try and do it with a macro. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: I would suggest making use of index(match()) functionality. Then this problem can be resolved using excel formula.

Comment: Great - thank you very much for the input - my table is now complete!  Thanks for making me see it much more clearly than I was thinking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a vlookup that returns a 1 or a 0, based on whether or not the value was present:
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$A$2:$B$20,1,FALSE),0)>0,1,0)

If you have all your unique c_ID values in a column (say A1), then copy the formula above into column B2. You will need to change the code to reference the range of values that you are performing looking up against though; so $A$2:$B$20 needs to be replaced with the full range of these values spanned by your original dataset (make sure to keep the dollar symbols) on Sheet 1.

Another option is to just replace $A$2:$B$20 with a named range. You can read about creating a simple range online and it is quite easy. Once you've named the range, you can just replace $A$2:$B$20 with your name and the formula should work.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Very helpful - thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question - very much appreciated.  C